# Cause of HTC MyTouch Slide Random Reboots

Tags: keyboard, reboot, crashes

I just bought a brand new HTC MyTouch Slide phone, so new it doesn't have a SIM card yet, but it reboots every time I slide out the slider. Sometimes it is a little delayed, but it is always while I am using the sliding keyboard. Usually it will boot back up right away, but sometimes it takes some time and a few tries to finally boot. Anyway, this thing spends more time rebooting than working properly.

Does anyone know the cause of this? Or even better, how to fix it?

Comment: Did that behavior exist from the first time you've switched on the device – or only later? If later: Have you done anything that might be related to it (any apps installed immediately before it started, or changed some settings)? Does the same thing happen while running the device in [safe mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)?

Comment: It actually did it once while I was doing the first time setup.

Comment: Hm: "reboots every time I slide out the slider" ‹› "It actually did it once"? So does it still happen – or was it a one-time event? And if it still happens, what about safe-mode (see my previous comment)?

Comment: I meant that one time, out of many, happened to be during the first time setup. As for safe mode, what is it? How do you enter safe mode?

Comment: As for [safe mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info), just follow the link. But if that issue already appeared in first-time setup, and the device being "brand new" – I'd simply return it to the dealer for replacement. Especially when it's that easy to reproduce. If the manufacturer srewed something up, let them have the fun to fix it :)

Comment: Thanks. I had just hoped I wouldn't have to do that, but I guess I will.

Comment: For a brand-new device and a situation like this, having it replaced is the variant you *will* prefer. If it's something with the hardware, you'd otherwise blame yourself later.